# RESTful master/detail

Tags: rest, hateoas

Having 3 dropdown pickers in a web application. The web application uses a Restful service to populate pickers data.

The two first pickers get their values from something like `/years` and `/colors`. The third one should get its values depending on the settings of the two.

So it could be something like `/models?year=1&color=red`.

The question is, how to make this HATEOAS-compliant (so that the dev does not have to know the way he should create an url to get the models).

The root `/` gets me a number of links, such as:

```
{
"_links": {
      "colors": "/colors",
      "years": "/years",
      "models": "???" }
}
```

What should be instead of `???`? If there was some kind of template `/models?color={color}&year={year}`, the dev would have to create the url. Is this OK?

Or there could be a link to list of years on each color got from `/colors` and then a link to list of models on each year got from `/years?color=red`, but i'd have to first choose color, then populate years and then populate models. Any idea if i want to have the model dependent on both color and year, not just the year populated from color?

Is it even possible in this situation to make it hateoas-compliant?

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of HATEOAS before, but based on what I just read about it, it seems that it supposed to return links to where the consumer of the service can go forward in the "state machine".

In your case that would translate to the links being "function calls".  The first two (`/colors` and `/years`) are functions that take no parameters (and return "something" at this point), while the third is a function call that takes two parameters: one that is a representation of a color, the other a year.  For the first two having a simple URL will suffice for the  link, but for the third, you need to include the parameter name/type information as well.  Something like:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "colors": "/colors",
    "years": "/years",
    "models": {
      "url": "/models",
      "param1": {"color"}
      "param2": {"year"}
    }
  }
}
```

Note: you can use the same layout as "models" for "colors" and "years" as well.

At this point the client knows what the URL to access the functions are and what the parameter (if any) names are to be passed to the function.

One more thing is missing: types.  Although you could just use "string", it will not be obvious that the "color" parameter is actually a value from what "/colors" returns.  You can be introducing a "type" Color that describes a color (and any functions that operate on a color: give a displayable name, HTML color code, etc.)

The "beefed up" signature becomes:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "colors": {
      "url": "/colors",
      "return": "/type/List?type=/type/Color"
    },
    "years": {
      "url": "/years",
      "return": "/type/List?type=/type/Integer"
    },
    "models": {
      "url": "/models",
      "param1": {
        "name": "color",
        "type": "/type/Color"
      },
      "param2": {
        "name": "year",
        "type": "/type/Integer"
      }
      "return": "/type/List?type=/type/Model"
    }
  }
}
```

Note: the path "/type" is used just to separate the types from functions, but is not necessary.

This will interchangeably and discoverably describe the functions, what parameters they take, and what values they are returning, so you can use the right value at the right place.

Of course implementing this on the service end will not be easy (especially with parameterized types, like "/type/List" -- think Generics in Java or templates in C++), but this is the most "safe" and "portable" way you can describe your interface to your clients.